# Silverlight/WPF runtime instpector

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

some times ago I've used Silverlight spy to profile a SL3 application... now I've to do the same on 5 but silverlight spy doesn't work anymore.... is there another tool that works with sl5/wpf?

for WPF I've tried snoop 2.8.0 but I can't attach to my WPF project...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Silverlight Spy works for me on an SL5 application.. But yes, as @Sankarann says - i think XAML Spy has now replaced Silverlight Spy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  [XAML Spy](http://xamlspy.com/)...

XAML Spy is the visual runtime inspector for Silverlight, Windows Phone, Windows Store and WPF apps. It provides unprecedented access to all aspects of any running XAML app. Interact with the UI visual tree, monitor events, extract XAML, explore the contents of the package and isolated storage, view statistics and more, much more.